# Can we have a countable universe if we weaken limitation of size to parameter free replacement in MK set theory?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Starting from [$MK$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory), if we

- replace the axiom of limitation of size by an axiom schema of *parameter free Replacement*, that is: any parameter free definable class bijection from a set domain, has a set co-domain, formally this is:

  If $\phi(y)$ is a formula in which only the symbol $``y"$ occurs free, and only free, then:

$$\forall f [\forall y (y \in f \iff \phi(y)) \land f \text { is a bijection } \land \\ dom(f) \in V \to codom(f) \in V]$$

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text { ; is  an  axiom} $.

- add the axiom that all sets are parameter-free definable, this is actually an [$\omega$-rule of class definability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3446781/is-choice-implied-by-class-definability-rule);
- and add the axiom that the universe $V$ is countable

> is the resulting theory consistent?

The point is that although replacement cannot use any class bijection between the universe $V$ [i.e. the class of all sets] and $\omega$ via parameters; still those class bijections are quantified upon in parameter free formulas of that language, so they can implicitly be used in replacement seeping through the quantified variables of the parameter free formulas!

Comment: Can you give an example of the last sentence?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "add the axiom that all sets are parameter-free definable"? What kind of defininitions for sets you allow? And how do you express definability in the language of MK?

Comment: @FedorPakhomov, parameter free definitions in the language of the theory of MK, all parameter free formulas are allowed. This is the definability inference rule given in posting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3446781/is-choice-implied-by-class-definability-rule

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar You could do this. However, it is strange to call an axiom something that is an infinitary rule. Could you please edit your question so that it would be completely clear what exactly is the (infinitary) deductive system for which you are asking whether it is consistent?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar There are still obvious issues with your formulation. Namely, there is an issue with your axiom that says that $V$ is countable. If it is specified as existence of class-function $F\colon \omega\to V$, then it trivially leads to a contradiction. Indeed, in your theory we would have the class $E=\{n\in \omega \mid n\not\in F(n)\}$ that will be different from any $F(i)$.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov, where is the problem? $V$ is the class of *sets*.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Sorry, indeed it isn't an issue. I missed that $E$ might not be a set.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar, I still don’t see how to use that class of bijections in your replacement axiom.

Comment: If what you mean is the question “Can the class of bijections implicitly be used in replacement?” then it is misleading to make the exclamation “That bijection can implicitly be used in replacement!” So I am voting to close as unclear, and downvoting the distasteful combination of omega rules, excessive exclamations, and an unmotivated axiom system.

Comment: I removed my answer, since there were a gap in the construction. Namely the theory that I had defined weren't closed under the infinitary rule. Pretty much sure it could have been repaired if we would start with least constructible model of (($\mathsf{ZFC}-$Power set)+there is a strongly inaccessible). However, it would then require forcing over $\mathsf{ZFC}-$Power set, which I am not completely comfortable with.

Comment: @MattF. I understood that the version of replacement described in the question was the scheme $\forall x\in V (\forall y\in x\exists! z\in V(\varphi(y,z))\to \exists w\in V\forall y\in \exists z\in w(\varphi(y,z))),$ where $\varphi(y,z)$ ranges over formulas of the language of $\mathsf{MK}$ without other free variables. However, indeed it isn't completely clear from the question.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar The phrase "class defines a bijection in a parameter-free way" is vague. Namely, the issue is that parameter-free definability isn't expressible in the language of $\mathsf{MK}$.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov, OK, then I'll write it formally for matters to be clear.

Comment: @MattF. The quantifiers in the formula of replacement (i.e. in $\phi(y)$) above can have bounded variables and those do range over all objects of the universe of discourse of this theory, so those bijections between the universe and $\omega$ would be within that range, because they are elements of the universe of discourse. So these bijections are not totally external to this theory. So they might cause problems. Hence the question.